# Using slider js with <picture>

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a small slider that switches the `preview` image to the `main` image. It works fine now

**blade.php**

```
<div class="custom-carousel-section">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="custom-carousel">
      @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
      <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        @if($loop->first)
          <span>{{ $article_block_image->title }}</span>
        @endif
      </div>
      @endforeach @endif
      @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
      <div class="main-image">
      @if($loop->first)
          <img src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
      @endif
      </div>
      @endforeach @endif
      <div class="img-to-select">
        @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
        <div @if($loop->first) class="img-to-select__item  selected" @else class="img-to-select__item" @endif>
          <img src="{{ $article_block_image->preview_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}" data-main-src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}">
        </div>
        @endforeach @endif
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function () {
$('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.main-image > img').attr('src', $(this).children('img').data('main-src'));
$('.custom-carousel__title > span').html($(this).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

But I still have a picture `mobile_image`, and I want the `mobile_image` to change instead of `main_image` at the maximum size of 576px, for this I use `<picture>`

I change my code to like this

**blade.php**

```
<div class="main-image">
    @if($loop->first)
    <picture>
        <source srcset="{{ $article_block_image->mobile_image }}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
        <source srcset="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
        <img src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
    </picture>
    @endif
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function () {
  $('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  let mainSrc = $(this).children('img').data('main-src')
  let mobileSrc = $(this).children('img').data('mobile-src')
  let title = $(this).children('img').attr('title')
  let alt = $(this).children('img').attr('alt')
  $('.main-image > picture').html(`
    <source srcset="{$mobileSrc}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="{$alt}" title="{$title}">
    <source srcset="{$mainSrc}" alt="{$alt}" title="{$title}">
    <img src="{$mainSrc}" alt="{$alt}" title="{$title}">
  `);
  $('.custom-carousel__title > span').html($(this).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

But it looks like something is wrong in the js code

> GET http://test.loc/blog/%7B$mainSrc%7D 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly looking at your code I think it's your string interpolation that's breaking.

`%7B` means `{` and `%7D` means `}`, so your code is not correctly interpreting your variable.

That's because the `$` needs to be outside the curly bracket.

`let example = ${variable}`, not `{$variable}`.

From the looks of things you're using some PHP view engine along with javascript, which probably confused you a bit.  In PHP your view engine is using `{{ $variable }}`, which will correctly interpret your PHP variables in the view engine.

In javascript the variables don't have any dollar signs, but when you use string interpolation with apostrophe the variable you use needs to be interpreted using `${variable}`.